# How to split a large file into small ones by line number

Tags: file, unix, split, numbers, line

I am trying to split my large big file into small bits using the line numbers. For example my file has 30,000,000 lines and i would like to divide this into small files wach of which has 10,000 lines(equivalent to 3000 small files).

I used the 'split' in unix but it seems that it is limited to only 100 files.

Is there a way of overcoming this limitation of 100 files?

If there is another way of doing this, please advise as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing program or are looking for help writing your own?

Comment: @RaymondChen, I know perl but if there is something like split which is fast i would prefer that.

Comment: If you want a prewritten program, then ask on SuperUser. If you want help writing your own, post the code you've written so far and ask a specific question.

Comment: You've tried `split -l 10000 -a 5 bigfile.txt`?

Comment: @Blender thanks, that is working perfect. Is there a way of doing it so that it file name starts from 1 and continues as 2, 3 ... rather than 00001, 00002,...?

Comment: you can always remove the leading zeros using the perl `rename` utility.

Comment: @FredrikPihl do i need to use this within a for loop do you think? or is there a more systematic and faster way than the for loop?

Comment: See my answer for howto use the rename-utility

Comment: @Blender, is there a way of making split results start from 1 rather than 0?

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU awk`

```
gawk '
BEGIN {
        i=1
    } 
    {
        print $0 > "small"i".txt" 
    } 
NR%10==0 {
    close("file"i".txt"); i++ 
    }' bigfile.txt
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/temp] seq 100 > bigfile.txt

[jaypal:~/temp] gawk 'BEGIN {i=1} {print $0 > "small"i".txt" } NR%10==0 { close("file"i".txt"); i++ }' bigfile.txt

[jaypal:~/temp] ls small*
small1.txt  small10.txt small2.txt  small3.txt  small4.txt  small5.txt  small6.txt  small7.txt  small8.txt  small9.txt

[jaypal:~/temp] cat small1.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

[jaypal:~/temp] cat small10.txt
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just added a way to do the renaming-part as requested in a comment

```
$ touch 000{1..5}.txt

$ ls
0001.txt  0002.txt  0003.txt  0004.txt  0005.txt

$ rename 's/^0*//' *.txt

$ ls
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  5.txt
```

I also tried the above with 3000-files without any problems.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I now just need to find a way that split results does not start from zero but 1. I guess i can change one file name manually in the worst case.